# Iterating child components inside a parent component using VueJS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

```
Vue.component('navmenu', {
    props: ['menu'],
    template: '<li><a :href="menu.url">{{ menu.name }}</a></li>'
})

Vue.component('navmenu-dropdown', {
    props: ['dropdownlist'],
    template: '<li>\
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ dropdownlist.name }}<b class="caret"></b></a></li>'
})
```

> Above are my parent components. The second component navmenu-dropdown
>   have a child component below.

```
Vue.component('navmenu-dropdown-li', {
    props: ['dropdownmenu'],
    template: '<ul class="dropdown-menu"> <li><a :href="dropdownmenu.url"> {{dropdownmenu.name}} </a></li> </ul>'
})
```

> Below is my HTML code to display the components.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-ul">
            <navmenu v-for="item in navlist" v-if="item.class != 'dropdown'" v-bind:menu="item"></navmenu>
            <navmenu-dropdown v-else v-bind:dropdownlist="item">
                    <navmenu-dropdown-li v-for="itemli in item.menus"
                                         v-bind:dropdownmenu="itemli"></navmenu-dropdown-li>

            </navmenu-dropdown>
        </ul>
```

> I am trying to iterate a json object of the format below:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#navbar-ul',
    data: {
        navlist: [
            {
                "name": "NJ Portal",
                "url": "/AG_ECAS/ecasHome",
                "class": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "SNEARS Home",
                "url": "/AG_ECAS/ecasHome",
                "class": "dropdown",
                "menus": [
                    {
                        "name": "USDA Memos",
                        "url": "/AG_ECAS/ecasHome",
                        "class": "dropdown"
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "Message from NJDA",
                        "url": "/AG_ECAS/ecasHome",
                        "class": "dropdown"
                    }
                ]
            }
         ]
    }
})
```

> I am able to see the main list like NJ Portal and SNEARS Home but the
>   child list is not showing up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting error due to `v-if/else`, item will not be available as the `v-if` will be false for second element, try following code, also `<navmenu>` should enclose the `navmenu-dropdown`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-ul">
   <navmenu v-for="item in navlist" v-bind:menu="item">
      <navmenu-dropdown v-if="item.class === 'dropdown'" v-bind:dropdownlist="item">
                    <navmenu-dropdown-li v-for="itemli in item.menus"
                                         v-bind:dropdownmenu="itemli"></navmenu-dropdown-li>
     </navmenu-dropdown>
  </navmenu>
</ul>
```